# Mac OS and iOS Free Anti-virus etc

Tags: macos, ios, anti-virus

Is there any anti-virus that is free for Mac OSX that is like AVG or Avast for PCs?

Is there a malwarebytes version for Mac OSX?

Is there mobile anti-virus available for iOS like Avast etc. I am looking for anti-virus that is compatabile on both iOS and Mac OS X. I am not just looking for anti-virus for Mac OS X.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a MalWareBytes for OS X; however, it is currently insecure because of the Sparkle updater bug.